# How to create different snapshots of database in Ruby on Rails 4?

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I have a rails application which has multiple models with associations among them. I would like to be able to do a number of things:
1. Track the CRUD changes ( I have used papertrail for this and seems to be good only to track the change and revert back to only that particular change)
2. Download different versions of the database/models at any time without affecting the current state of database.

Regards
Suren